# Having trouble with paths

Tags: python, path

Alright, so I need to, in my instructors own words: 
-Read in all of the images in the images directory
-Creates a histogram for each image. Your histogram function cannot use the PIL function Image.historgam.

I've got this basic code so far:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):
    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)
    return loadedImages
path = "/

imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
    img.show()
```

---

With the issue being the path = / bit. I do not know how to word it properly so that the program reads a file called "images" from my desktop (or anywhere else I can put it if you recommend).

Please respond as soon as possible, I can't progress in my assignment until I do this.

Comment: You didn't mention what went wrong when you ran your code. That's an important part of figuring out what the problem is. BTW, print is your friend. Do `print(path+image)` in your for loop to see what you get.

Comment: "With the issue being the path = / bit. I do not know how to word it properly so that the program reads a file called "images" from my desktop (or anywhere else I can put it if you recommend)."

Comment: Your code reads all images in a directory but you say you want to read a single file called "images". Confusing!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `os.path` for working with file paths.

```
import os

for filename in filelist:
    full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
```

You should also consider that `os.listdir` also includes directories in its results. Also, there's a possible error in your code where you define `path`, it looks like you're missing a closing quote.

Comment: My issue is I have no idea what my path or filelist is. This did not work.It caused an error about literals.

Comment: How do you intend to open files if you don't know where they are? `path` should be something like `"/path/to/mypics"` and `filelist` should be `os.listdir(path)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.join(path, filename)` to create the file path:

```
import os
import os.path
from PIL import *

def loadImages(path):
    return [PImage.open(os.path.join(path, image)) for image in os.listdir(path)]

for img in loadImages('/'):
    img.show()
```

Comment: I can't use PIL for the histogram, and I still don't know how to path from my school's timmy drive.

Comment: go to the folder with the photos, right click one of the photos, click `properties`, look what `location` is

Comment: Thank you Uriel! I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that

- prompts the user for a path to scan
- uses os.path.join to build file names
- filters out subdirectory names
- catches PIL errors

I think it covers the original requirements

```
import os
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):
    # paths to files in directory with non-files filtered out
    images = filter(os.path.isfile, (os.path.join(path, name) 
        for name in os.listdir(path)))
    loadedImages = []
    for image in images:
        try:
            loadedImages.append(PImage.open(image))
            print("{} is an image file".format(image))
        except OSError:
            # exception raised when PIL decides this is not an image file
            print("{} is not an image file".format(image))
    return loadedImages

while True:
    path = input("Input image path: ")
    # expand env vars and home directory tilda
    path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars(path))
    # check for bad input
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        break
    print("Not a directory. Try again.")

imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
    img.show()
```